# Advanced search based on web properties of a site and managed metadata properties of a document

Tags: search

Lets say I have a site called: Customer1
Which represents the documents for that customer.

Inside the Customer1 site, I have web properties(property bag) like:
ClientCode: 123
CustomerName: Customer1
YearAcquired: 2012

Lets say we have 1 content type called deliverables, this content type has a field called
ProjectName.

All our sites point to an enterprise search center.

Now the user wants to make searches like this:
ContentType=Deliverable and ClientCode=123 and ProjectName:xxx

As you can see the content type deliverable does not have the client code, the client code is in a web property of the web where the document belongs to and I am combining managed properties from the document and web properties too.

I doubt this is possible the way it was designed (not by me)

Any thoughts?

Comment: What version of SharePoint? 2013 allegedly has the ability to crawl the Property Bag of certain objects...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS I thought, in SharePoint 2013 you can index the Property Bag, but you gotta tell SharePoint about it -

(PowerShell Example)

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://localhost
$web.AllProperties["Prop1"] = "value1"
$web.IndexedPropertyKeys.Add("Prop1")
$web.Update()
```

From:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2012/08/06/searching-property-bags-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx

Comment: We already have the properties as indexex properties, but the question was, if that kind of search can be done? when properties are in different scopes( web vs document)

Answer (score 1):

You may need a custom two step solution that locates the site (Path) based on the Site Properies and then "refines" on the Document properties in that path. Your page could perform the "two step" for the user without their knowledge.